# How do I put HTML in a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, html, listview

How do I put HTML being read from external storage in a ListView in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an html file inside the **assets** folder, then load it in a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) inside the listview using this.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); //www is a directory
```

Comment: @RodManiego can you please clarify? and yes you can put pictures in the webview, but in that case, why not just use an imageView?